# how to close all collapse onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my html5 codes...

```
<div class="col">
                <div class="title">Sizce Ak Parti 2019 Seçimlerini Kazanır Mı?</div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="card animated bounceInDown">
                        <div class="card-header bg-danger text-center">
                            2019 Seçimleri
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" id="blankRadio1" value="option1" aria-label="..."> Evet kazanır.

                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="radio" name="blankRadio" value="option1" aria-label="..."> Hayır Kazanamaz.</li>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="index.php" role="button">Gönder</a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is jquery codes...

```
<script>
        $(function () {

            $(".title").click(function () {
                $(".content").stop().slideUp();
                $(this).next().stop().slideToggle();
            })

        })
    </script>
```

but when i refresh chrome page. this collapse always open onload. but i wanna closed a collapsa. how am i do this.  by the way sorry for my english.

Comment: Probably because of the `bounceInDown` class. What css library are you using for animations?

Comment: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ this one. animate.css

Comment: Seems pointless to use both css animations and jQuery animations. Just remove that class and set the css to hide the cards when page loads

Answer (score 0):

Just add an instruction to collapse all the panes on page load:

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $(".content").slideUp(); // Close all the panes

        $(".title").click(function () {
            $(".content").stop().slideUp();
            $(this).next().stop().slideToggle();
        })

    })
</script>
```

Comment: I'm grateful for your help. i am new here.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want the panes to slideUp when the page first loads. The idea is to invoke the method that hides the panes when document is loaded and is ready to be manipulated.

```
$(function () {
  function doToggle () {
    $(".content").stop().slideUp();
    $(this).next().stop().slideToggle();
  }

  // bind the click event listener
  $(".title").click(doToggle);

  // hide the panes
  doToggle();

});
```

Comment: <script>
    $(function () {

        $(".content").slideUp(); // Close all the panes

        $(".title").click(function () {
            $(".content").stop().slideUp();
            $(this).next().stop().slideToggle();
        })

    })
</script>

i did with this codes. you think your ideas much than better this?

Comment: it's fine either way.